# If every $0$ digit in the expansion of $\sqrt{2}$ in base $10$ is replaced with $1$, is the resulting sequence eventually periodic?

Tags: number-theory, decimal-expansion

If every $0$ digit in the expansion of $\sqrt{2}$ in base $10$ is replaced with $1$, is the resulting sequence eventually periodic?

Comment: Since the sequence is not periodic, if you change zero to any number, it will still be non periodic since other numbers at other places also decide periodicity.

Comment: @jnyan that's not true

Comment: A periodic sequence would have a finite numbers repeating, say 95467,95467,95467..... Say this was obtained by changing some digit, say changing 4 to 5, then original sequence would have been 94467,94467,94467, a repeating sequence. I can't think  of any counterexamples

Comment: Possibly relevant : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/971137. I quote [Milo Brandt](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/174927/milo-brandt) : "Strictly speaking, it is unknown whether $\pi$ with every $4$ changed to $6$ would be irrational (since we don't know even that every digit of $\pi$ occurs infinitely often), but if it's a [normal number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number), then it would still be irrational".

Comment: @jnyan : I think you actually proved the converse : if $x$ is rational, then replacing every $0$ digit by $1$ yields a rational number $y(x)$. But here it is a different question: $x_0=\sqrt 2$ is _irrational_, but does it follow that $y(x_0)$ is irrational? For instance, $x=0.10100100010000…$ is irrational but $y(x)=0.1111111…$ is rational.

Comment: @watson, no I meant to get a rational by changing only one digit, the original number should also be rational. And the question is to get rational from irrational

Comment: @jnyan : the question is about changing "every $0$ digit", not only one of them.

Comment: It has not been answered by anybody, since I had posted  the question here.